# how can I write netflix zuul filter to change response location header attribute?

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have downstream service that redirect to x.jsp this location is not in gateway route for example

```
gateway route --- localhost:8080/app - 192.168.1.1:80 (DownStream app)
```

in DownStream app when a user is not logged in, it redirects to 192.168.1.1:80/Login.jsp, which is in the `Location` header of the response.

This URL is not using the gateway.

I want to write a zuul filter to change this redirect url by mapping in zuul routes dynamic for example for each url that routes in zuul filter change `Location` header by the gateway. How can I do that?

Comment: So did you try a Zuul filter to do this and it did not work?

Comment: yes dose not work

Comment: Can you provide a sample application?

Comment: Or any configuration or any more information than "it's not working"?

Comment: can we see some code to determine what you tried and whats failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You downstream app should respect the x-forwarded-* headers, and not generate redirects like that. But the following filter will change the redirect location for you anyway:

```
@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "post";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    int status = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getResponseStatusCode();
    return status >= 300 && status < 400;
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = ctx.getZuulRequestHeaders();
    Optional<Pair<String, String>> locationHeader = ctx.getZuulResponseHeaders()
                .stream()
                .filter(stringStringPair -> LOCATION.equals(stringStringPair.first()))
                .findFirst();

        if (locationHeader.isPresent()) {
            String oldLocation = locationHeader.get().second();
            String newLocation = ...
            locationHeader.get().setSecond(newLocation);
        }
    return null;
}
```